# Xamarin Forms- Relative Layout- Align Top of 1st View to Bottom of 2nd without adding them in a Vertical StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to add views in a relative layout.

I need to align them vertically/ horizontally with respect to each other's edges. Not with respect to the parent view.

But it seems that the Xamarin relative layout API can only provide relative layout alignments with respect to the parent `RelativeToParent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xamarin forms do support RelativeToView

```
    <RelativeLayout>
    <BoxView x:Name="topBox" 
             Color="Red"
             RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=Width,
                  Factor=0.6,
                  Constant=0}"
             RelativeLayout.XConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=X,
                  Constant=20}" />

    <BoxView 
        Color="Blue"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,
            Factor=0.6,
            Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=topBox,
            Property=Y,
            Constant=40}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=topBox,
            Property=X,
            Constant=0}" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As Kojan points out, there is `Constraint.RelativeToView`.

For XAML and C# examples, check out:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/#Understanding_Constraints